# What does the build configuration "profile" do?

Tags: qt5, qt-creator

I just upgraded to Qt 5.6.0. I noticed something that I did not notice before. A new project in Qt Creator gets now three build configurations: "release", "debug" and "profile", It seems to me that "profile" is new. If so what is its purpose?

Comment: My guess is that it is connected with [profiling of the application](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html).

Comment: Additionally "profile" build configuration is not mentioned in [Qt Creator's change logs](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/dist) and in the documentation. I believe documentation should mention "profile" [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html) - as it mentions "debug" and "release".

Comment: For starters, the profile build configuration fails to build for Android projects; guess it was just thrown in there by someone who needed it in the usual Qt half-assed, untested way; my recommendation is to ignore it, i.e. remove it from the generated project.

Answer (score 9):

When I looked at Projects -> Build steps -> Effective qmake call, 
I have found this additional CONFIGS:

```
"CONFIG+=force_debug_info" "CONFIG+=separate_debug_info"
```

Also I found [some comments](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-October/018690.html) for them that could clarify why this is needed:

> Hello all,
>
> once more I'm preparing a Qt 5 build for profiling purposes and wonder again
>   why there is no way to combine -release and -debug in Qt's configure
>   script. The only way to get a sane build for profiling Qt code itself that
>   I know of is hacking the mkspec and ensuring that -g is added even in
>   -release mode.
>
> Is there any reason for that? Could we improve this situation somehow to
>   make it simpler to get a Qt build with optimizations and debug symbols?
>
> Am I missing the recommended way to get this done?

This option produces release builds (with all compiler optimization), but with debug symbols (pdb files) that are required for testing performance of C++.

Answer (score 1):

According to the online Qt documentation (Breadcrumb: "Qt Creator Manual" > "Specifying Build Settings", end of 1st paragraph):

> A **profile configuration** is an optimized release build that is delivered with separate debug information. It is best suited for analyzing applications.

Link can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html). I'm still a Qt newbie, and have personally never used this configuration.